# Canvas tag - drawarc vs image

Tags: performance, html, canvas

I've implemented a canvas element that uses drawarc to create the effect of bubbles rising up at various speeds on the background (it's an underwater themed site for an underwater-themed client) - It looks really good and I'm pretty pleased with it, but I'm noticing a slight performance issue in some browsers (specifically IE9).

I'm drawing the bubbles using drawarc to create semi translucent circles - can anyone tell me if this is more or less expensive (in terms of client side performance) to stamp images/sprites onto the canvas instead?

-Mike

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Drawing arcs / circles is much more expensive than drawing images. Drawing images is most likely the most efficient method for drawing anything to a canvas. I wrote my [Bachelor Thesis](http://www.danielbaulig.de/ba-thesis/) on this subject. It is in german, but basicly when drawing arcs using arc and arcTo you get less than 15.000 operations / sec in IE9. When drawing images you get more than 160.000 operations per second.

Comment: Thanks buddy, gonna try this out now.

Comment: Okay - I implemented it with images instead of arcs and did see a slight increase in IE9 performance (not loads, but then what I am doing here isn't so intensive anyway, i am sure the images method would scale much better).

Comment: You might be able to speed up your canvas drawing by only repainting the parts of your canvas that actually changed. You can do this by setting a clipping region using clip before clearing and repainting the rectangle. Additionally you can do visibility culling against the clipping region to only actually call the painting methods on those items that lie within the dirty rectangle. These are well known techniques to speed up graphics drawing. They might not be apllicable in your case though. Also if you have perofrmance issues,  profile them and figure out what your bottleneck actually is.

Comment: I find that multiple over-load canvases with transparent backgrounds, along with context.clearRect(x,y,w,h) the most efficient. In Pacman, for example, I have static elements such as the maze on the bottom canvas, a middle layer of pills for Pacman to eat, and a top layer of dynamic sprites: this allows the ghost sprites to move over the pills without the need for redrawing, and Pacman can clearRect() when he's eaten one.

Comment: @DanielBaulig, Link is broken.